# Determine if image is a photo

Tags: c#, .net, image, photo

I am just sittning on the Metro and was thinking about images. Is there any way to determine if a image is a photo or not? I dont want to use the file extension becaus it can be whatever.

Is there any .net c# way or plugin to analyse the image?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: Photo compared to what? If a screenshot of text, sure you can compare JPEG quality and PNG compression ratios.

Comment: Well if it's a JPEG you could extract the EXIF info.  If present, then more than likely it was taken by a camera (includes aperture; shutter speed etc) and not something pasted in PBrush and saved as a JPEG.

Comment: @MickyDuncan ty, thats one way. There is no other way on different file extensions? How about raw images? I guess that i can determine if they are photos by looking at the meta.

Is there any way to meashure the photo gloss?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any .net c# way or plugin to analyse the image?

Yes, you can use [Emgu, openCV wrapper for .net](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
With openCV you can get the text string inside the images.
Or even you can detect a smile of people on your image.

Comment: Not sure if OP is after machine learning for detecting _traffic signs; mushrooms or faces_, rather whether it _"is a photo or not"_.  The ML in this example would have to be trained for every conceivable object

Comment: Maybe we need the definition of a photo in this case. openCV can detect everything like circle, rectangle and other objects. If it is just has text and not text then it is simple.